# img called with php not showing

Tags: php, html

i'm trying to call an image with php, the source is called correctly but the image isn't show, only the space in blank with the "alt" of it. I try with deactivating ad bloc in the browsers (the problem happens in google chrome, firefox and iOS safari, but doesn't in safari OS X) but it didn't any change and as i say before it get the right path and everything when i inspect the element. the name of itself for the case is "omg/perfiles/ecangis.png" and the code is:

```
if(empty($perfil['fotoperfil']) === false){
echo '<img src="', $foto,'" alt="Foto de perfil de ', $perfil['name'],'" style="width:100px; height:100px;">';
}
```

Does anybody know why the image isn't show and how could i make it appear?? also wouldn't be the worst to know if i deactivated ad bloc wrong, is there any way to code a way to jump it??

Answer (score 3):

Try making the concat with a point :

```
if(empty($perfil['fotoperfil']) === false){
    echo '<img src="'.$foto.'" alt="Foto de perfil de '.$perfil['name'].'" style="width:100px; height:100px;">';
}
```

Comment: :) I guess I beat you by few seconds but I will vote you up.

Answer (score 2):

Its not `,` its `.` to concatenate on to the echo / string use period

```
if(empty($perfil['fotoperfil']) === false){
echo '<img src="'. $foto.'" alt="Foto de perfil de '. $perfil['name'].'" style="width:100px; height:100px;">';
}
```

Comment: Well i changed that, but didn't make any differense, that only change how the php code work, which have always work without problem, the location of the image is called, the problem is that the browsers don't show the image itself

Comment: @Ecangis can you show me what comes on screen when you run my code?

Comment: Kind of yes and kind of no, actually is not right now since in the webpage that I'm making you already need to be registered to see this and, well, the page is in Spanish... Let me arrive home, change this and then post the link.

Comment: @Ecangis I don't need access to the page or the link just copy past the output that you see on the screen. You said the image doesn't show, could you copy past what does display on the screen. Maybe it says something like ERROR or something

Comment: I will need that you excuse my ignorance in this, should I copy what's on the element inspection or someone like a page-print?? Because otherwise on the screen don't say any error or something alike, but show the square of the image with the sign of android "broken" and the title of the image

Comment: ok That is great ... That means that your $foto has a wrong path or image doesnt exist. try to do echo $path or inspect element and see if the path is correct. @Ecangis

Comment: actually yes, the path is correctly shown what i have found is that when the photo it's uploaded a image is generated with the respectably height and width but the image is blank, i have append this code in a response below

Answer (score 0):

So, the code was actually alright with the "," or the "." , so i guess that the problem have to be in the php of the upload file or the function that upload the photo and create the file in the server, being this:

```
if( empty($_FILES['fotoperfil']['name']) === false){
            $tipos = array('jpg','jpeg','gif','png');

            $file_name  = $_FILES['fotoperfil']['name'];
            $file_ext   = strtolower(end(explode('.', $file_name)));
            $file_temp  = $_FILES['fotoperfil']['tmp_name'];
            $size       = getimagesize($file_temp);

            if($size[0] !== $size[1]){
                $errors[]="Las fotos deben mantener la proporcion cuadrada establecido, por favor edita la foto en tu computador antes de subirla.";
            } else if($size[0] > 400 or $size[1] > 400){
                $errors[]="Las fotos pueden tener un tamaño maximo de 400 pixeles, puedes disminuir su tamaño en el computador y tratar de subirla denuevo";
            }

            if (in_array($file_ext, $tipos) === true){

                if(empty($user_data['fotoperfil']) === false){
                    borrarfoto($user_data['userid'], $user_data['fotoperfil']);
                }

                cambiarfoto($user_data['idname'], $user_data['userid'], $file_temp, $file_ext);
            }
```

and the function:

```
function cambiarfoto($name, $userid, $file, $ext){
$name = sanitize($name);
$file = sanitize($file);
$ext = sanitize($ext);

$file_path = 'img/perfiles/' . $name . '.' . $ext;  
move_uploaded_file($file, $file_path);
mysql_query("UPDATE `usuarios` SET `fotoperfil` = '" . mysql_real_escape_string($file_path) . "' WHERE `userid` = " . (int)$userid);
}
```

when the image is called the element is shown like this:

```
<img src="img/perfiles/ecangis.png" alt="Foto de perfil de Enzo" style="width:100px; height:100px;">
```

Comment: When you do the upload does it show in your img/perfiles folders?

Comment: Yes, and with the right name and everything, that's why I can't figure it out

Comment: something funny is that the file of the image is created on the folder, with his extension and everything, but the image is blank, i mean is plane white